# Drupal footer template?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-templates

How should I name the footer template file in my subtheme for it to work with these kind of statements in other template files?

```
<?php print render($page['footer']); ?>
```

(I am using panels but perhaps that is not relevant here.)

Answer (score 0):

According to Drupal 7 [community documentation](https://drupal.org/node/225125):

```
Any .tpl.php files from the parent theme will be inherited. You can add template files with more specificity — for instance, node--blog.tpl.php building on an inherited node.tpl.php.
```

Therefore you can name the template file for the footer region as: **region--footer.tpl.php**

Comment: Thank you, I tried this before but it is not picking up (though I flushed the cache). Can I debug this somehow?

Comment: Is there any block assigned to this 'footer' region?

Comment: I am not using the Blocks module. Only Panels. Thanks.

Comment: The regions you see in the Panels are different from the regions that are defined in the Drupal theme in the .info file.

Assign some block to the footer region via STRUCTURE->BLOCKS and it will display right away.

Comment: Thanks, when I assigned a block to the footer the template did kick in. But the content of the block is not showing in the template?

Comment: It can be because of the faulty configuration of the block. Assign multiple blocks and check if any output is shown.